# MySQL prepared statement produces error with Django, but works in command line

Tags: python, mysql, django

MySQL table has 3 columns - region, month and revenue with values like this

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7pPT.png)

I have written a query which groups revenues by month for each region

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT("SUM(CASE WHEN region = ", QUOTE(region)," THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS ",
         CONCAT('`', region, '`')))
  INTO @sql
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE region IS NOT NULL AND region <> '') RTD;


SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(month, '%M-%Y') as Months, ", @sql, "
,SUM(revenue) as `Grand Total` FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY month ORDER BY month ASC" );

PREPARE region_stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE region_stmt;
```

which produces results like this (this is the desired result) in command line and sequel pro

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HepuV.png)

But when I use same query with Django 1.8 with python 2.7 cursor, it produces error

> ProgrammingError: (1064, u'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT\r\n         CONCAT("SUM(CASE WHEN region = \'", `regio\' at line 2')

I have used single quote instead of Quote() also, but got same result

```
CONCAT("SUM(CASE WHEN region = '", region,"' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS ",
```

Python code

```
from django.db import connections
crsr = connections['rmd'].cursor()
crsr.execute(query)
```

Comment: It looks like something in your code is escaping quotes and newlines.

Comment: Show us your Python code!

Comment: @KlausD. I have added Python code. I have different escape options, but none worked in this case.

Comment: You missed the most important part: the `query`.

Comment: query is just a multi-line string mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are already escaping quote and newlines so try avoiding quote() around regiorn

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
     CONCAT("SUM(CASE WHEN region = ", region," THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS ",
     CONCAT('`', region, '`')))
INTO @sql
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE region IS NOT NULL AND region <> '') RTD;
```

you should check for the real content of sqlcode in your app and adapt your dinamic command build to the feauture of your runtimen app env

Comment: have you checked  for the  sql code  generated  by Djaingo ???   .. update your question and add the  real sql code generated  by Django

Comment: SQL code generated is same as I posted earlier. I just added print(query) to the code and got same statement